# Jquery change event not firing in wrapped telerik component

Tags: javascript, jquery, telerik

I have a telerik timepicker component which is wrapped by company framework.

```
<div class="t-widget t-timepicker" style="margin-left: 5px;"><div class="t-picker-wrap">
```

`<input class="t-input" id="RealEndTime" name="RealEndTime" type="text" value="07:05" autocomplete="off">`

[image]

My problem is I am trying to trigger a change event when a value is selected from dropdown list which is opened my clicking the clock icon. Since the input area is text, I can trigger change if I write time in box (not choosing from list) but I cant trigger change event if I select a time from list.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume this is a Telerik Kendo UI timepicker.  If so, you should be able to set the events when you call the kendoTimePicker() method.

```
function onChange() {
    //change event code
}


  $("#timepicker").kendoTimePicker({
        change: onChange                      
   });
```